# Reading the link attritube on the itemClick

Tags: php, apache-flex

```
<root>
<module label="Executive Library" >
                        <node label="Document one"  link="http://www.google.com" />
                        <node label="Document Two"  link="http://www.google.com" />
                        <node label="Document Three"  link="http://www.google.com"/>
                </module>
```

I have a page which displays these items, when i select the document One i need the link associated to be clicked. How can i achieve this programatically.

Comment: W/o code and punctuation your question is meaningless

Answer (score 2):

It sort of depends on which set of controls you're using, but most likely you're looking for something like "event.item.@link", where the "@" signifies "attribute" -- for example:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.MenuEvent;

        private function onMenuItemClick(event:MenuEvent):void
        {
            trace(event.item.@link);        
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:PopUpMenuButton itemClick="onMenuItemClick(event)" labelField="@label">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:XML xmlns="">
            <module label="Executive Library" >
                <node label="Document one" link="http://www.google.com" />
                <node label="Document Two" link="http://www.google.com" />
                <node label="Document Three" link="http://www.google.com"/>
            </module>
        </mx:XML>
    </mx:dataProvider>
</mx:PopUpMenuButton>
```

Here, I'm just using your XML (minus the root node) to populate a PopUpMenuButton's dataProvider, and capturing the itemClick event that way.  Hopefully that's what you're doing as well -- post back and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the Help, 

  private function itemClick1(event:ListEvent):void
        {
                Alert.show(event.item.@cd_link.toString);                
        }

Why this throws an error and i am using TREE component.

Comment: What's the specific error?  From that code snip, one thing I see is that you should be using "toString()", not just "toString".